Extract multi-level bullet point contents from a tab delimited text file
I have a text file containing two level bullet points in the format below. I have splilted them in lines.
What I would like to do is to extract all contents that belong to the first level bullet points, NOT each individual bullet point. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Example:
- Control System:
    - Use microcontrollers (e.g., Arduino Nano) for control.
    - Implement Bluetooth modules for remote control via smartphone apps.
    - Include safety features like automatic shut-off.
- Safety Features:
    - Overheat protection for the motor.
    - Childproof mechanisms to prevent accidental activation.
....
....

What I would like to extract:

Control System: Use microcontrollers (e.g., Arduino Nano) for control. Implement Bluetooth modules for remote control via smartphone apps.
Safety Features: Overheat protection for the motor. Childproof mechanisms to prevent accidental activation.

I tried regex but I can only extract the first level or all bullet points but I was not able to join the desired ones together.

"and I believe it is tab delimited": you are not sure? "I tried regex": have you not tried anything else? Like just reading line by line and accumulating?

Suppose you have:
inp='''\
    - ABCD
        - abcd
            - xyz
    - EFGH
        - efgh
''' 

You can parse that with a regex and python native string methods:
>>> [''.join([e.lstrip('\t- ') for e in m.splitlines()]) for m in re.findall(r'(?m)^\t- ([\s\S]*?)(?=^\t-|\Z)', inp)]
['ABCDabcdxyz', 'EFGHefgh']

That is assuming:

Tab separated
The bullet -
All the bullets are together.

But it is easily modified

Many thanks for your answer. It seems that I oversimplified my task. I have modified the question. Could you have a look at it again please?

I have done it! I modified the regex in the link you provided to ^- ([\s\S]*?)(?=^-|\Z) thank you!
